# Combinatory: how many differents queues are possible...

Tags: combinatorics

**Problem:**

> $50$ people go to teather. The price of the ticket is $5$\$.
>   $25$ of these people have only a $5$\$ note in their wallet, while the other $25$ only have a $10$\$ banknote. The cashier doesn't have any cash at the beginning of the queue. I would like to know how many queues exist such that the cashier always has the possibility to give the rest.

For instance: if the first person pays with a $10$\$ note, the queue does not work, so we know that the first person who pays, needs to pay with a $5$\$ note, because if the first one comes with $5$\$, then the second one can pay with $10$\$, since in this case the cashier would have the rest.

So, how many different queues are possible?

**My thoughts**:

I thought i would have found the solution by finding the number of arrangements of $50$ elements by using only $\{0,1\}$, where $0$ stands for a person who pays with a $5$\$ note, while $1$ stands for a person who pays with a $10$\$ note. In this way I know that the number of $0$s must always be bigger or equal to the number of $1$s, if you read the arrangement from left to right.

I also found that this number must be smaller than $\dfrac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} 50 \\ 25 \end{pmatrix}$, so a half of total number of arrangements.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Look for information on Catalan numbers.  E.g., http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number

Comment: [here](http://webspace.ship.edu/msrenault/ballotproblem/Four%20Proofs%20of%20the%20Ballot%20Theorem.pdf)